# Why is mov eax,val not the Intel-syntax equivalent of mov $val,%eax?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I'm trying to understand the differences between Intel syntax and AT&T syntax (I am using GNU as).

I have two files, intel.s:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

val:
    mov eax, val
```

and atandt.s:

```
val:
    mov $val, %eax
```

I am trying to convert the AT&T version to the Intel version. But I get different results:

```
$ objdump -d intel.o

intel.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <val>:
   0:   a1 00 00 00 00          mov    0x0,%eax
```

and

```
$ objdump -d atandt.o

atandt.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <val>:
   0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
```

Why are they different?

Comment: In intel syntax you should use `mov eax, offset val` to load the address.

Comment: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html one is mov immediate, other is mov from dword

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Understood now!

Comment: This is one of the ways that `.intel_syntax noprefix` is different from NASM syntax.  It's more like MASM, which uses exactly the same `offset` keyword and where a plain symbol is a memory operand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Intel instruction loads the contents of val. To load its address, use

```
    mov eax, offset val
```